# Higher Kinded Types in Scala and Haskell

Tags: scala, haskell, higher-kinded-types

[Data.Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Foldable.html) shows the following algebraic data type:

`data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)`

Its `kind` is `* -> *`. It requires an `a` type.

```
Prelude> :k Tree
Tree :: * -> *
```

Let's look now at `trait Foldable[_]`, a "higher-kinded type" from Scala from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/):

```
trait Foldable[F[_]] {
  def foldRight[A,B](as: F[A])(z: B)(f: (A,B) => B): B
  ...
}
```

The excellent book says:

> Just like values and functions have types, types and type constructors
>   have kinds. Scala uses kinds to track how many type arguments a type
>   constructor takes, ...

**EDIT**

When specifying `trait Foldable[F[_]]`, does the `F[_]` always indicate a higher-kinded type? Is it possible for `F[_]` to be anything else? Could it be a type - `F[A]`?

Comment: I am looking forward to this answer.  I too am a little confused with how type traits on higher-kinded types in Scala are declared, then implemented with "instances" for each concrete type, and finally used with an implicit instance of the higher-kinded type.

Answer (score 5):

The `F[_]` in Scala stands for something like `* -> *` in Haskell: that is a type which "receives" a concrete type (the `_` in Scala and the first `*` in Haskell) and returns a new concrete type (`F[A]` for some concrete type `A` and concrete "container" `F` in Scala).

So yes, `F[_]` stands for some higher kinded type like `List[_]` or `Option[_]`. It wouldn't be useful to define traversable in scala like `trait Foldable[A,F[A]]` because we would be saying that `Foldable` needs to be defined with the specific thing being folded (the `A`).

Comment: `List[_]` is not a higher kinded type, but an existential type (at least when you want to refer to `scala.List` and not an arbitrary type parameter that is named `List`). The higher kinded type would be just `List` or `Option`.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't asked much of a question, but if you want a general idea: yes, the "kind" system of both of these languages is a type system for their own type system. The `*` type is not a wildcard but a special type atom; `*` is the type of "concrete types" like `String`, `[String]`, and `Tree String`.

In turn there are things like `[]` or `Tree` (see the difference?) which have kind `* -> *`; this is the type of "singly-parametrized types" which take a concrete type and produce another concrete type.

A last example: there are things called "monad transformers" like `MaybeT` which takes a monad like `IO` and produces another monad like `IO . Maybe` (if you will pardon the use of function composition operators where they're not generally admitted). What kind does that have? Why, `(* -> *) -> * -> *` of course: monads have kind `* -> *` so we take one of those types and transform it into another of those types.

I cannot speak with so much expertise on Scala syntax, but on the Internet we see a definition of a monad transformer trait in Scala as:

```
trait MonadTrans[F[_[_], _]] {
  def lift[G[_] : Monad, A](a: G[A]): F[G, A]
}
```

so I think your guess is mostly right (that the brackets indicate a dependent type).

Having a type theory of these things guarantees that you never write things like `IO IO` as a concrete type, or `MaybeT String`.

Answer (score 2):

`F[_]` *in that context*, i.e. as a type parameter to a class or method, always means a higher-kinded type, aka a type constructor. You can also write it as `F[A]` but would normally only do that if you were going to reuse the `A` to express a constraint, e.g. `trait Something[F[A] <: Iterable[A]]`.

As the book says, the kind constrains what things (types or type constructors) can be put there. You can have a `Foldable[List]` or a `Foldable[Option]`, because these are 1-argument type constructors, but you can't have a `Foldable[String]` or a `Foldable[Either]`. Likewise you can't have a `Foldable[List[Int]]`, because `List[Int]` is an ordinary type like `String` (i.e. of kind `*`). And you *can* have a foldable  for the type that is `T[A] = Either[String, A]`, because that is a 1-parameter type, aka a 1-argument type constructor, aka a type of kind `* -> *`, though you have to write it using the somewhat excruciating syntax `Foldable[({type T[A]=Either[String, A]})#T]`. And you can see that it would only be possible to implement the given `foldRight` for "types" (type constructors) `F` that have the correct "shape"; if `F` is `Int`, then what would `F[A]` be?

There is a different scala usage of `F[_]` to mean an existential type, `F[A] forSome { type A }`; try not to get confused by this, they're unreleated.

Comment: Not to derail the answer, but that excruciating type lambda syntax - that is one of the things the typelevel guys have fixed in their compiler, right?

Comment: Yes, or you can use the kind-projector plugin with the mainline compiler.